# Canonical vec operator in Eigen

Tags: eigen

What is the best (canonical) way to implement a [vec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics))-operator in eigen? I am sure that this ubiquitous operator would be implemented, but I can't find it in the documentation.

Currently, for matrix `M`, I do:

```
Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXd> tmp(nullptr, 0);
new (&tmp) Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXd>(M.data(), M.size());
```

Answer (score 1):

There is [conservativeResize](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1PlainObjectBase.html#a4ac24a195e3e35ce2d8946cee5873e51), which is not you're looking for, as that may actually change some of the values. Personally, I use your method (except for the placement new). You can also specify that the Map is aligned. The Map is a way of looking at the same memory with a different view (*e.g.* reshaping). If you want an actual reshaped object, you can create a copy (via a Map). You can also use `resize` which is a no-op if the size is the same. I don't think resizing will work of fixed size matrices, but a Map will. Run the code below for an example.

```
Eigen::MatrixXf mat;
mat.resize(3,3);
mat << 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9;
std::cout << mat << "\n\n";
mat.resize(9, 1);
std::cout << mat << "\n\n";
mat.conservativeResize(1, 9);
std::cout << mat << "\n\n";
```

Comment: Can I use the same conservativeResize method for vectors and matrices of all sizes and flavours (dynamic, fixed sized)?

Comment: The reshape example is where I got my code from, but it's still a far cry from an actual vec-operator.